# Asp.Net Core 2.0 - Custom Middleware dependency injection

Tags: jwt, middleware, asp.net-core-2.0

I have written custom middleware for JWT Token generation (based on code from some tutorials for Asp.Net Core 1.1) This middleware uses some dependencies: 
 **DbContext, UserManager, SignInManager**

I am upgrading my Asp.Net Core Web API from 1.1 to 2.0 version of ASP.NET. 
And after most of the modifications from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x 
I have encountered such an error:

```
Application startup exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'MyApplicationWebApi.Models.DatabaseContext' from root provider.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

My Middleware constructor looks like this:

```
#region constructor 
       public JwtProvider(RequestDelegate next,
                          IOptions<JwtProviderOptions> options,
                          DatabaseContext dbContext,
                          UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
                          SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager) 
       {
           _next = next;
           _options = options.Value; 

           // Instantiate through Dependency Injection 
           _dbContext = dbContext; 
           _userManager = userManager; 
           _signInManager = signInManager; 
       }
       #endregion
```

I have also seen that in new tutorials, books for ASP.NET 2.0 the JWT token generation is usually resolved using some TokenController endpoint rather then custom TokenMiddleware. And I have a question:

1. Should I migrate from using custom middleware **JwtProvider** to **JwtProviderController** ?
2. Can I inject **DbContext, UserManager, SignInManager** into custom Middlware? (I have read that into constructor I can only inject **singleton** DI's services, and into Invoke() I can inject **scoped** DI's services. Is that true, and are **DbContext, UserManager, SignInManager** such scoped services.)
3. In Program.cs I have created some scope using 
   **host.services.CreateScope()** maybe I should make something like this in Custom TokenMiddleware?